# Inexplicable Issue with Add Method of a Simple Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

My binary tree looks pretty close to my class materials, but when I print to the console or check for contains(), any adds I'm doing aren't registered.

I don't have a great understanding of `static` and the debugger is giving me a hint about making a static reference to non-static variable `overallRoot`, but everything compiles without error or warning in eclipse.

```
public class BSTSimpleSet<E extends Comparable<E>> implements SimpleSet<E> {

private GTNode<E> overallRoot;
private int size;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BSTSimpleSet<Integer> main = new BSTSimpleSet<Integer>(2);
    main.toString();
    main.add(3);
    main.toString();
    main.add(4);
    main.toString();
    main.add(5);
    main.toString();
    System.out.print(main.contains(3));
}

public BSTSimpleSet() {
    size = 0;
}
public BSTSimpleSet(E input) {
    overallRoot = new GTNode<E>(input);
    size = 1;
}

public boolean add(E e) {
    return add(e, overallRoot);
}

private boolean add(E e, GTNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new GTNode<E>(e);
        size++;       
        return true;
    } else {
        int compare = e.compareTo(root.data);
        if (compare == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (compare < 0) {
            return add(e, root.left);
        } else {
            return add(e, root.right);
        }
    }
}

public void clear() {
    overallRoot = null;
}

public boolean contains(E e) {
    return contains(e, overallRoot);
}

private boolean contains(E e, GTNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        int compare = e.compareTo(root.data);
        if (compare == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (compare < 0) {
            return contains(e, root.left);
        } else {
            return contains(e, root.right);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (overallRoot == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public int size() {
    return size;

}

public String toString() {
    this.toString(overallRoot, 0);
    return null;
}

private void toString(GTNode<E> root, int level) {
    if (root != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            System.out.print("     ");
        }
        System.out.println(root.data);
        toString(root.left, level + 1);
        toString(root.right, level + 1);            
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            System.out.print("     ");
        }
        System.out.println("_");
    }
}

private static class GTNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    public E data;
    public GTNode<E> left;
    public GTNode<E> right;

    public GTNode(E input) {
        this(input, null, null);
    }

    public GTNode(E input, GTNode<E> lNode, GTNode<E> rNode) {
        data = input;
        left = lNode;
        right = rNode;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: im debugging but just not very good at it. i have been doing the things you mentioned. for example the size variable does increment when i call add() but contains() & toString() don't seem to be traversing the tree references that add should also create.

Answer (score 1):

This code does absolutely nothing.

```
private boolean add(E e, GTNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new GTNode<E>(e);
        size++;       
        return true;
    }
 ...
```

Java passes in the Object Reference to a method. If you change the Reference, that will not
be propagated back to the calling method. If you change what the Reference refers to
that will be propagated back.

eg

```
// arrays behave the same way so using them to illustrate.
public void callMethods(){
    int[] array = new int[1];
    array[0] = 0;
    doesNotChange(array);    
    System.out.println(array[0]);// will print 0
    doesAChange(array);    
    System.out.println(array[0]);// will print 1
}

public void doesNotChange(int[] myArray){
    myArray = new int[1];
    myArray[0] = 1;
}

public void doesAChange(int[] myArray){
    myArray[0] = 1;
}
```

To avoid these sorts of things I recommend always setting method parameters final.

Answer (score 0):

The GTNode class shouldn't be static. Static classes are classes with only static methods, which means they don't have to be instantiated. The prototypical example of this is the java.lang.Math class: You don't need to call something like `Math m = new Math(); m.cos();` to get the cosine, you just call `Math.cos()`. Since you're creating multiple instances of the GTNode class, make it non-static and you should be good.